# How to open drawer manually in flutter 2.2

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a Drawer button on the right side of the appBar, now I am trying to open that by calling

```
Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer()
```

it doesn't work.
also, I followed a defined way in flutter example itself it doesn't work either.
can someone please help me with how to open the drawer manually in flutter 2.2?
code is attached below!
Thanks in advance

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  void _openDrawer() {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState?.openDrawer();
  }

  void _closeDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: _openDrawer,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu_sharp,
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
        ],
      ),
      body: Text('This is Profile Page'),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Explain what doesn't work. What's the error?

Comment: when I click on the menu icon it doesn't open the Navigation drawer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is solved by adding a key in the Scaffold _scaffoldKey

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: _openDrawer,
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu_sharp,
                color: Colors.black,
              )),
        ],
      ),
      body: Text('This is Profile Page'),
      drawer: Drawer(),
    );
  }
}
```